# How to hide Intellisense "based on recent edits" suggestions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

What the title says.

I don't mind them being in the "Error List" because they're only marked as "Messages" so they can easily be filtered, but I'd like to hide the dots in the code.

Comment: Could you please describe your problem more clearly? What did you mean that Intellisense “based on recent edits” suggestions?

Comment: Hi ispiro, any progress about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle this issue:) If my answer helps you handle this issue, please do not forget to accept it. And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To turn off the "Based on recent edits" stuff, go to [turn off IntelliCode suggestions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/intellicode-suggestions#disable-intellicode-suggestions).

Per the docs:

> If you wish to turn it off, choose Tools > Options, IntelliCode General tab, and then switch C# suggestions to Disabled

[image]

This will turn off "Based on Recent edits" while still leaving on the other stuff like code styles/autocomplete/etc.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019: `C# deep-learning base model for completions = Disabled`

Comment: In VS 2022: turning off `Promote likely items in Intellisense completion lists` did it for me.

Answer (score -2):

> How to hide Intellisense “based on recent edits” suggestions?

If you want to hide such suggestion in Intellisense(show as a `dot`), you should add this below on the top of every cs file:

```
#pragma warning disable xxx(suggestion ID)
```

**Or** use `#pragma warning disable` to disable every suggestion.

For an example, I have make a similar sample:

[image]

[image]

================================================================

**And** usually to remove that Intellisense Suggestion, you should enter **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Text Editor**-->**C#**-->**Code Style** and then find such suggestion message and change its **Severity** from `Suggestion` to `Refactoring Only`. With this, you could remove such Suggestion on **Code Editor**.

[image]

**Since** I did not know your specific suggestion message(based on recent edits) and the **ID** and also not sure whether such suggestion are in the Code Style menu, so I suggest you could try my first solution.

**Note that:** So far, no matter which way you suppress the suggestion, removing `dot` in the **Code Editor** will also remove the message in the **Error List**. They are unified, you cannot suppress the **IntelliSense** in the **Code Editor** and save the message in the **Error List**.

**Besides,** if you still want this,you could suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8).